# Road to String Theory

Tags: string-theory, soft-question, education

I have a question for our theoretic SuperUsers. How much knowledge and which fields of physics you have to know to start studying string theory? I am now on QFT, after I think I'll start study Supersymmetry or maybe special cases of QED. How much more should I know to start Strings? :)

Comment: If you've mastered the content of, say, Peskin and Schroeder's text on QFT, you may want to study conformal field theory, and then I would suggest you are ready to learn string theory. A solid background in differential geometry and certain aspects of algebraic geometry/topology will also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to master algebraic geometry (in particular derived functor cohomology of sheaves, say EGA 1-3), algebraic topology (characteristic classes, say the entire book of Spanier), commutative algebra and algebra in general (say Lang's book and A/M), and also homological algebra (the entire book of Weibel).

Comment: Sorry, could you clear up what A/M means/refers to?

Comment: Atiyah/Macdonald, introduction to commutative algebra (classical text in commutative algebra)

Answer (score -1):

Probably just Quantum physics and astronomical physics.
Those are a couple of the most important fields you should know to start string theory.